# Is FileChannel's ClosedByInterruptException Avoidable?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, file, io

I have a multi threaded program that uses a `SingleThreadExecutor` to write data to the disk (It waits in an infinite loop using a `BlockingQueue`). When I want to essentially shut it down, I use the `Future` object to cancel it (followed by `executor.shutdown()`). This has the effect of interrupting the `Thread` which contains the `FileChannel` and thus throws a `ClosedByInterruptException` is there any way to avoid this happening? I seem to be losing data when the channel is closed in the middle of doing work. Should I not use the interrupt mechanism and instead turn the infinite loop into a loop on a `volatile` `boolean`? Are there alternative ways of solving this problem?

Comment: Write a 'shutdown' object to the `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: Rather than calling Future cancel method , call executorsService shutdown , that will wait for current task to get executed by thread and no new task will be added in queue

Comment: @coreJavare That won't work because of the infinite loop in the task thread.